# Absolute minimum code to detect keypresses via mousekeyhook C#

Tags: c#, mousekeyhook

I want to create a log of keypresses in C#. I found keymousehook but I don't get how to use it. I couldn't find a comprehensive guide or a blog post.

The documentation isn't really helpful either. What is the absolute minimum code to detect keypresses? Can it be used in a Console Application?

Comment: give https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/documentation a try

Comment: If you want to create a log of KeyPresses, then Key**Mouse**Hook won't help you. [This article on keyboard hooks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/) shows how to do it with a **keyboard** hook.

Comment: @stuartd That is what I actually needed. Is there something similar for the mouse.

Comment: [Low-Level Mouse Hook in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at. This could be used in a console application.

https://github.com/twenzel/SurfacePenNavigator/blob/master/SurfacePenNavigator/KeyboardHook.cs